# Importance of penance in life

Tags: shiva, ramayana, bhagavad-gita, maya, yogi

I have been once informed by my GURUDEV that everything one gains in life is because of some or the other **penance performed earlier**,i.e., we have enjoyments at the cost of losing something or being deprived of something on the other hand.

Even SRI RAMCHARITRAMANAS by GOSWAMI TULSIDASJI mentioned verse that "it's only by penance that Lord Brahma creates, Lord Vishnu maintains and through penance only Lord Shiva annihilates."

So, how important is it for any modern YOGI to wisely understand the importance of penance in life while ignoring the dualities of gain and loss, etc and practice peacefulness at all times irrespective of the circumstances?

Answer (score 2):

Presuming yajna being the correct Sanskrit term for penance, Sri Krishna described the same in Bhagwat Geeta in Chapter 4 from verse nos 24 to 30. And the significance of any yajna is described in the following verses -

> BG:4.30- ... All these indeed are knowers of yajna & **through yajna their sins are cast away.** 
>   BG:4.31- ... **This world (of Brahman), is not for him who offers no yajna, much less the world hereafter**. 
>   BG:4.32- ... You also knowing yajna, **reach liberation by breaking away from bondage.**

So, yajna, whether internal or external, is basically to cast sins away or to break away from the bondage.

Comment: But sin is a relative term, 'yajna' in above seems refering to the times during we are able to live under the shelter of our own soul say during meditations, else mind, karmas takes over the control

Comment: Yajna is not the Sanskrit word for penance. Tapas is. Vedas mention that the world is upheld by Tapas.